# what is the intention of pointer to pointer typecasting?

Tags: c, pointers

i have seen a block of code which allocates memory pool. A line in the block of code says

```
*(char**) block = nextblock;
```

can any one help what is the intention of typecasting a `char*` block as `*(char**)`?

Comment: You can't dereference a void pointer implicitly which is typically used for generic coding in languages like C. The cast is also to disambiguate pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Dariusz Don't you mean `char**`?

Comment: Can i see a bit more code, including actual types for both variables?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum i'm almost sure it's quite valid to dereference void**. But not void*, ofc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reason why such typecast should be done other than for code readability.

Dereferencing a `void**` pointer is allowed and not even frowned upon by my `gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)`, called with `gcc -pedantic dereferencetest.c`

```
struct StructTest {
  char* ptr;
};

int main(void)
{
  char* str = strdup("test");
  char** ptr = &str;
  void** vptr = ptr; // warning here
  char* strRecycled = *vptr; // no warning on dereferencing

  printf("str=[%s]", strRecycled);


  {
    struct StructTest val;
    struct StructTest* structPtr = &val;
    struct StructTest** structPtrPtr = &structPtr;

    vptr = structPtrPtr; // warning here
    structPtr = *vptr; // no warning on dereferencing
  }


  return 0;
}
```

There are warnings regarding invalid pointer type assignment and initialization, but no dereferencing warnings.

```
dereferencetest.c:9: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
dereferencetest.c:20: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis the warning is in another place. Not in the derefencing itself. Edited the answer for clarification.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis have you read the question? Is it about the assignment? Have you read my answer? It actually says the same thing you do, *it is legal*, the difference is that I posted a proof.